# How to turn off check-ins?

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, google-now

I have an Android 4.1 phablet. I'd like to turn off the check-in feature. The only way I've found so far is to disable the whole Google Now, but I don't want to do that.

**I want to turn-off only check-ins feature.**

I want to do this because it's extremely annoying, even when I stay in my apartment for hours and don't move my phone. It proposes to check-in to thousands of places around every few minutes. (I live in city center)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to adjust the settings in the Google Maps application that control this. Launch Maps and press the overflow menu icon (the three dots in the bottom right on Vanilla Android; you may need to access your settings slightly differently on other devices with custom UI skins), then go to `Settings => Location settings` and scroll down. You should see a subsection labeled "Check-ins":

[image]

If you also want the cards for nearby places to be hidden then you can do that in Google Now's settings. Select `Settings => Google Now => Places` and turn those cards off.

Comment: Yeah, "Check-in notification" this is the thing I want to disable. However, in Google Maps I have no 3 dots icon anywhere... (Actually you are speaking about 3 squares?)

Comment: @WojciechBednarski: Yes, I guess it's more like three squares stacked on top of one another. It's in the bottom right (in portrait, anyway) and should look like this: http://www.google.com/help/hc/images/android/android_ug_40/ic_menu_overflow_dark.png

Comment: Ok, found it! Its inside Google Maps settings as you described and looks like on your screen. I just have no this dots/squares probably due to samsung modification or something

Comment: @WojciechBednarski: Ah, that's probably it. I'm using a Galaxy Nexus, so I don't have Samsung's UI skin.

Comment: Thanks, you save my day. Yes these 3 squares are not in my version of Google Maps, but I can see it in other places. I have Note 2 with android 4.1.1 so probably Samsung made soem changes.